# How to clear the MySQL screen opened through the MySQL Command Line Client on Windows XP

Tags: mysql, windows, command-line, cmd

How do i clear the MySQL screen, which I opened through the MySQL Command Line Client?

The operating system is Windows XP.

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: Did you get the command which will clear thiw problem?

Comment: @harigm nope. Windows doesnt have it. Linux has though.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is a number of solutions in Linux like [this one](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/192466), but the consensus seems to be there is none for Windows. See e.g. [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,140151,140151#msg-140151) or [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_21769823.html) (scroll to the bottom)

Answer (score 92):

> **Note**: Please see @Pekka's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514950/736809) for the Windows version, which seems to be that there is none for windows. However, [this](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/192466) is a useful post to take a look at for windows. The remainder of this answer shows how you can do it in **Unix / Linux** and exists for historical significance as it has clearly been useful to some users.

To clear the editor screen in Unix/Linux you can type:

```
system clear
```

This makes use of mysql's [`system` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-commands.html#idp11302256) to call the shell's [`clear` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/clear).

Note: the `system` command works only in Unix.

Comment: This is the first link I found when googling how to clear the MySQL screen. I feel this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: I guess this is not the accepted answer because the OP uses Windows XP. Sadly, he didn't mention in the question but in a comment. It's kind of late to edit the question now, though, since there're already excellent answers for the Unix family.

Comment: To truly clear the screen (so that you can't scroll up and see the previous content), use `system reset` (see [this Ask Ubuntu answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/25079/124558)).

Comment: Scary sounding to type "system clear" from within MySQL but it works as expected ;-)

Comment: @Jimbo: *I feel this should be the accepted answer...* - except that its the wrong operating system. Since it does not answer the question, it should probably be deleted as such :)

Comment: @jww Fair point. Still, the first link I found was helpful :-) **Edited**.

Answer (score 15):

```
\! clear
```

Since 'clear' is a Linux operating system command and Linux and Mac OS X are
both forms of Unix, this command might very well work fine for you too.

Please note that the '! ' in front of the clear command is used to tell
MySQL to pass the command back to the OS to handle.

Watch this activity: [How to clear the MySQL screen opened through the MySQL Command Line](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcbmE56O87U)

Answer (score 14):

You could use `system clear` like @Singamalai mentioned or even use keyboard shortcut like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

**I know this question is for Windows but since so many answers have been provided already I just thought to extend it for Linux users also so it will be beneficial for future users too.**

So in Linux you can do

> Ctrl + L

to clear the MySQL command window running through terminal.:)

Answer (score 3):

You can clear the screen with:

```
system cls
```

Or alternatively

```
\! cls
```

Comment: doesn't work here, and neighter any combination of `\!`|`system` + `clear`|`cls` (winXP)

Comment: Hmm, I'd test it myself if i was on windows, but "system clear" works on OS X and Linux, and if I recall correctly, the command to clear window is "cls" in Windows

Comment: Won't work in Windows, I just tried. There seems to be no way to do this in Windows.

Comment: This answer is not valid. `system` is an internal mysql command that doesn't work on Windows. And `cls` is an internal Windows command that doesn't work on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I need to work on my stuff, I use Windows PowerShell to drop into the mysql shell. The only way I've found to clear the screen is to

1. Exit mysql
2. Type `cls` at the powershell prompt
3. Drop back into the mysql shell again

It's a kind of workaround, but it works for me, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I done this workaround for Windows
Right-click on the top frame of console -> Properties -> Layout -> and set Screen Buffer Size Height to large number.