# What is the method for clearing the screen on mysql command line?

Tags: mysql

I am facing the problem while trying to clear screen on MySQL.Could anyone please help me
to solve this problem.While there is no issue in the oracle.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514914/how-do-i-clear-the-mysql-screen-opened-through-the-mysql-command-line-client

Comment: Just by curiosity, do you have any specific *need* to clear the screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514914/how-do-i-clear-the-mysql-screen-opened-through-the-mysql-command-line-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

```
system clear
```

**Solution 2**

```
\! clear
```

**Solution 3**

```
/c
```

Not possible on Windows:
See this link from SuperUser: https://superuser.com/questions/196806/is-there-a-command-to-clear-the-screen-of-mysql-under-windows

Comment: Did you try the second solution Make?

Comment: yeah I also tried that but that is also generating same error.

Comment: Did you try Solution 3 ? Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Oh boy, looks like its not possible on Windows, but only on Linux

Comment: Solution 3 also not working for me what should I do now@Ali Gajani

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35299/discussion-between-make-and-ali-gajani)